# Change accumulator by reference or create new

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I was on interview few days ago and at some part of my code like this:

```
array.reduce((acc, el) => ({
    ...acc,
    [el.id]: [el.value]
}), {})
```

But after discussion interviewer ask me to rewrite solution to be better performed like this:

```
array.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.id] = el.value;
  return acc;
}, {})
```

I understand, that copying accumulator every time is not a good solution, but I saw first solution so many times and though that changing accumulator by reference is a bad practice.

So, which code is preferred?

Comment: It's like every new invention, people often misuse it lacking a deeper knowledge of what actually happens under the hood.

Comment: You're not using the accumulator elsewhere, so why would you copy it every time, especially for only updating a single field?

Comment: "I understand that copying accumulator every time is not a good solution" <= to me, if I was a recruiter, that speaks volumes.  If I was a recruiter, I want people who think logically and make decisions based on facts.  Not based on practices they have seen repeated frequently

Comment: A rule I often use is don't modify objects that are finalized. When you know you are building an object/structure it is fine to modify it.

Comment: "*which code is preferred?*" is an opinion-based question that StackOverflow isn't really suited to answer. See the duplicate for some discussion - there are arguments for either. But if you care about performance (and the array is large), there's only one choice.

Answer (score -1):

I think your interviewer wants to see you make a for loop, when parsing a LOT of data performs better.

for example:

```js
let acc = {}
for (let i = 0; i < array.length, i++) {
   const el = array[i];
   acc[el.id] = el.value;
}
```

Comment: "when parsing a LOT of data performs better" Where are you getting this information from?

Comment: from my experience, we switched a reduce in a for loop and the code runs 2 times faster.

and here the benchmark
https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2472/0/arrayreduce-vs-for-loop-vs-arrayforeach#latest_results_block

Comment: @Tomma5o [Don't trust microbenchmarks!](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html) A little change (probably making it easier for the compiler to inline the reduce callback) [causes largely different results](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/11030/0/arrayreduce-vs-for-loops-vs-arrayforeach).